# Intersection of interpol1d objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I have 2 cumulative distributions that I want to find the intersection of. To get an underlying function, I used the scipy interpol1d function. What I’m trying to figure out now, is how to calculate their intersection. Not sure how I can do it. Tried fsolve, but I can’t find how to restrict the range in which to search for a solution (domain is limited).

Answer (score 0):

Use scipy.optimize.brentq for bracketed root-finding:

brentq(lambda x: interp1d(xx, yy)(x) - interp1d(xxx, yyy)(x), -1, 1)